# how give custom permissions to a group of analysts in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

in TFS 2018, how I Can set permission to my users (developer analysts people) in such a way that they behave like this:

- see the test plan, and enter to detail
- disable Test bar. The might not run teh test.
- they can write in summary
  -they can change the state.

I've read a lot of info but not find the correct solution.
Or I give full access to test plan or is only imited to see the plan, but not interact with it.

Link I've visited:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=tfs-2018
- https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=vsts#area-path-object-level

There are some solution, or I only can use the defaults options?

I set the permission in the last image, Security Tab. My user is Admin.
My template project is CCMi.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Work items (including test plans and test cases) have all-or-nothing permissions in terms of editing. Either you can edit it (which means you can change every field), or you can't change anything. That's it.

There's no way to change this behavior.